# Октябрь или октября?

Tags: грамматика

Ноябрь холоднее октябрь или октября?

Answer (score 3):

Конечно же *октября.* Склонения никто не отменял.

Можно, конечно, добавить *"чем":*

> Ноябрь холоднее, чем октябрь.

Тогда падеж будет именительный. Но без *чем* звучит проще и лучше.

Comment: Ну это смотря для кого проще. Если человек путается с падежами именительный - он всегда проще.

Comment: Ну да, соглашусь с вами. Я под простотой имел в виду в первую очередь краткость в данном случае. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ноябрь холоднее октября. Это родительный падеж: холоднее (чего? кого?) октября. Он похож на винительный и студенты-иностранцы и вообще те, у кого русский не родной, могут спутать. Но надо запомнить, что при  сравнительных степенях прилагательного требуется именно родительный.